# How to right align a CMFCLinkCtrl?

Tags: visual-c++, hyperlink, mfc

I have just added a [`CMFCLinkCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfclinkctrl-class?view=msvc-170) to my dialog:

`CONTROL         "od 9:42-44",IDC_MFCLINK_OD_REFERENCE,"MfcLink",WS_TABSTOP,289,143,42,11`

Looks like :

[image]

At the moment it is not mapped to any variable because I have set the URL and Text within the IDE. But I would like this tooltip to be right aligned. It doesn't change size but to be sure I do not want it to flow to the right any further. Is this possible?

I have reviewed the available properties in the IDE and there are no text alignment controls:

[image]

Comment: `LWS_RIGHT` style maybe?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou can that style be directly used in the RC file?

Comment: Haven't tried it, maybe yes. manually. Otherwise programmatically. Also, `CMFCLinkCtrl` inherits from `CMFCButton` which contains a member called `m_nAlignStyle` - don't know if it works in the `CMFCLinkCtrl` implementation though.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou To do the latter then I would most likely have to map to a control variable before trying to set that alignment style.

Comment: The properties pane contains the `Align Text` property. It sets the `LWS_RIGHT` style in the resource, if you select `Right`. Tested, and it works in Win10, although the documentation says "Windows Vista". Doesn't it work in your installation?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Maybe I overlooked the property in the IDE. It is latent so I will try in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou This does nothing `m_linkOD.m_nAlignStyle = CMFCButton::ALIGN_RIGHT;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to use the [`CHyperlink`](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/117333/making-the-cmfclinkctrl-class-more-developer-frien) control. It is derived from `CMFCLinkCtrl`.

In the comments to my question the suggestion was made to make use of the `m_nAlignStyle` property. This seemed logical because the link control is derived from `CMFCButton`. But that does not work.

The `CHyperlink` control does use the aforementioned property but has a bespoke `OnDraw` handler:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Set the alignment for the hyperlink.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOL CHyperlink::SetTextAlignment(HyperlinkAlignment enumValue)
    {
    if (enumValue == Left)
        {
        m_nAlignStyle = ALIGN_LEFT;
        //SizeToContent(TRUE, FALSE);
        Invalidate();
        }
    else if (enumValue == Right)
        {
        m_nAlignStyle = ALIGN_RIGHT;
        //SizeToContent(TRUE, FALSE);
        Invalidate();
        }
    else if (enumValue == Center)
        {
        m_nAlignStyle = ALIGN_CENTER;
        //SizeToContent(TRUE, TRUE);
        Invalidate();
        }
    else
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

    return TRUE;
    }
```

Notice that I commented out the `SizeToContent` calls since it did not make sense to do that. If you size the control to the content then what is the point of supporting alignment (apart from vertically)?

In my case, by:

1. Using `CHyperlink`.
2. Adjusting the `SetTextAlignment` method.

It would work. Example:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::InitODLink(CHyperlink& rLinkCtrl)
{
    const LanguageMSA eForeignLang = theApp.GetForeignLanguageGroupLanguageID();
    const CString strODLink = GENERALLABEL3(eForeignLang, IDS_STR_OD_WOL_LINK);
    const CString strODTooltip = GENERALLABEL3(eForeignLang, IDS_STR_OD_WOL_TITLE);

    if (eForeignLang == LanguageMSA::Arabic)
    {
        rLinkCtrl.SetWindowText(_T("ش م 9:42-44"));
    }

    rLinkCtrl.SetURL(strODLink);
    rLinkCtrl.SetTooltip(strODTooltip);
    rLinkCtrl.SetTextAlignment(CHyperlink::Right);
}
```